# X5690 compatibility + HP DL360 G6

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, central-processing-unit, intel

Does anybody know if the X5690 is compatible with the HP Proliant DL 360 G6?

I got a pair of X5690s and a DL 360 G6 but i am unable to get any video signal. The fans spin up like crazy and that is about it...

As far as i can tell i already installed the latest, April 2015, service pack upgrades but still no dice.

Any ideas or does this CPU not work with the DL 360 G6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel X5690 CPU is not compatible in an HP ProLiant DL360 G6 server. The X5670 is the fastest 6-core CPU that will work in that model...

This is a heat/power constraint on the DL360 G6/G7 platform.

When my specifications called for X5680 or X5690 CPUs, I needed to use G6 or G7 *DL380* 2U servers to accommodate them.

Comment: Thanks i was afraid that would be the case, it just seems strange that the X5690 seems to be supported in the DL 160 G6 which is also a 1U server utiziling the Intel 5520 chipset.

Answer (score 0):

There is an advisory about a ROM upgrade dated 2013-08-15 that lists that system amongst others and apples to a small number of processors including the X5690. The Intel chipset used on the MB does support it.

> [Advisory](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=3884313&docId=emr_na-c03898078&docLocale=en_US): ProLiant Servers with Certain Intel Xeon Processors -
>   CRITICAL SYSTEM ROM UPGRADE REQUIRED for Intel Xeon X5675/X5687/X5690
>   Processors to Prevent a Rare Possibility of System Crashes or
>   Unpredictable System Behavior

Comment: Yeah i read it too, it seems to imply that the X5690 can work in the DL 360 G6.